# Iterating through response.data not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, vue.js

Lets say my response.data is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "person1": [
            {
                "name": ....
                "age": xx
            }
        ],
        "person2": [
            {
                "name": ....
                "age": xx
            }
        ],
        "person3": [
            {
                "name": ....
                "age": xx
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

If I wanted to add a `gender` field to each person, I try to do it via the map function like this:

```
axios
    .get('...')
    .then(response => (this.people = [response.data].map(person => {
        person.gender = "";
        return person;
    })))
```

This adds only one `gender` field to the `response.data` and not to each person. What am doing wrong?

My desired result would be like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "person1": [
            {
                "name": ....
                "age": xx
            },
            gender: ""
        ],
        "person2": [
            {
                "name": ....
                "age": xx
            },
            gender: ""
        ],
        "person3": [
            {
                "name": ....
                "age": xx
            },
            gender: ""
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not even valid javascript possible structure...

Answer (score 0):

You're not iterating over the nested objects in `response.data`. `[response.data]` makes an array with one element, that element is the entire `response.data` object. Then you're adding the `gender` property to that object, and returning an array with this object.

You should iterate over the elements of `response.data`. You can use `Object.values()` to get an iterator of these values.

```
this.people = Object.values(response.data).map(person => ({...Object.values(person)[0], gender: ''}))
```

Working demo:

```js
let response = {
    "data": {
        "person1": [
            {
                "name": "Person 1",
                "age": 10
            }
        ],
        "person2": [
            {
                "name": "Person 2",
                "age": 25
            }
        ],
        "person3": [
            {
                "name": "Person 3",
                "age": 47
            }
        ]
    }
};

let people = Object.values(response.data).map(person => ({...Object.values(person)[0], gender: ''}));
console.log(people);
```

Comment: The explanation makes sense, but for some reason am still getting the same outcome. Can you explain the `person` parameter?

Comment: The `response` parameter is the current element of the `map()` iteration.

Comment: I didn't notice that there's another level of array nesting within the `personX` properties. Why do you have that? Can there be multiple objects there? I've updated the answer to assume it's always just one object.

Comment: let me clarify, I would like the gender to be outside the array of person properties. how can I achieve that?

Comment: Update the question to show what you want `this.people` to look like.

Comment: i suggest for you to edit your question accordingly with the structure you desire. we both have provided answers but it gets unclear what you want

Comment: How could the gender be outside the array? Don't you want `{name: xxx, age: xx, gender: ''}`?

Comment: yes, it's strange. I would assume he would either prefer your structure with an array of objects or preserve the origin structure like I did. But either way, gender being outside of `{name: xxx, age: xx, gender: ''}` it makes no much sense.

Comment: This is an example code, for my use-case, I can have more than one array in every object (person in this example) but would like to add one property only to each object (person).

Comment: What is `this.people` supposed to be? `map()` always returns an array. Do you actually want an object like `response.data`?

Comment: You probably just need some nested loops that modify `response.data` in place, rather than returning a new array.

Answer (score 0):

given your response structure, you could extract first `reponse.data` entries (which will return an array of arrays containing key and values).

after you can use reduce where first param is the accumulator, and second will be the current `[key, value]` you are iterating. `value` is the array, since `value[0]` is the object, you can create your next array as `[ { value[0], gender: '' }]`

```js
const response = {
    "data": {
        "person1": [
            {
                "name": 'john',
                "age": 33
            }
        ],
        "person2": [
            {
                "name": 'mary',
                "age": 22
            }
        ],
        "person3": [
            {
                "name": 'diego',
                "age": 14
            }
        ]
    }
}

console.log(
  Object.entries(response.data).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = [ { ...value[0], gender: ''} ]
    return obj
  },{})
)
```